# Doesn't stop CURSOR loop when update result rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I want to set `DriverID` column  of `Driver` Table to 5000, 5001 ,....

For this purpose I write this script :

```
use WeighbridgeDB
GO

DECLARE @NewDriverID int;
SET @NewDriverID = 5000;

DECLARE Driver_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DriverID FROM Driver
FOR UPDATE;

OPEN Driver_Cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM Driver_Cursor

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE Driver SET DriverID = @NewDriverID WHERE CURRENT OF Driver_Cursor;
    SET @NewDriverID += 1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Driver_Cursor
END

CLOSE Driver_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Driver_Cursor;
GO
```

But the While loop doesn't stop and the value of `@@FETCH_STATUS` is always 0. I think the Cursor rebuild itself since update occur on table or something.

How to correct this situation?

thanks.

Comment: I guess you are missing out INTO after fetch next from driver_cursor

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani - you don't *need* `INTO`. It means that the row will be sent to the client of the connection instead. And since the OP isn't trying to use any value from the current row, it's not obviously wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a cursor for this anyway (generally speaking try and avoid these in TSQL except for very few cases)

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DriverID) + 4999 AS NewDriverID
FROM Driver
)
UPDATE T SET DriverID = NewDriverID
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do it like this:

```
UPDATE Driver
SET
    Driver.DriverID = d.NewDriverID 
FROM
(
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() Over (ORDER BY DriverID) + 5000 AS NewDriverID,
        Driver.DriverID 
    from Driver 
) AS d
WHERE Driver.DriverID = p.DriverID
```

There is almost never a reason to use a cursor.